# GTID have been turned off But I have error in replication

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, mariadb, slave

I just upgrade from mariadb5 to mariadb10. Then I have error on my slave replication

> Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist

My master for this replication does not using GTID, why is this error appear. Although I'm having this error my slave_IO and slave_SQL still running.

This is my slave status for reference

> *************************** 1. row ***************************
>                  Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
>                     Master_Host: 172.19.19.149
>                     Master_User: slave
>                     Master_Port: 3306
>                   Connect_Retry: 10
>                 Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000385
>             Read_Master_Log_Pos: 564
>                  Relay_Log_File: migrate-relay-bin.000002
>                   Relay_Log_Pos: 535
>           Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000385
>                Slave_IO_Running: Yes
>               Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
>                 Replicate_Do_DB: 
>             Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
>              Replicate_Do_Table: 
>          Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
>         Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
>     Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
>                      Last_Errno: 1146
>                      Last_Error: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist
>                    Skip_Counter: 0
>             Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 564
>                 Relay_Log_Space: 834
>                 Until_Condition: None
>                  Until_Log_File: 
>                   Until_Log_Pos: 0
>              Master_SSL_Allowed: No
>              Master_SSL_CA_File: 
>              Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
>                 Master_SSL_Cert: 
>               Master_SSL_Cipher: 
>                  Master_SSL_Key: 
>           Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
>   Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
>                   Last_IO_Errno: 0
>                   Last_IO_Error: 
>                  Last_SQL_Errno: 1146
>                  Last_SQL_Error: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist
>     Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
>                Master_Server_Id: 30
>                  Master_SSL_Crl: 
>              Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
>                      Using_Gtid: No
>                     Gtid_IO_Pos:

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I already fix the replication by run the mysql_upgrade that I forgot to run after updating MariaDB from 5 to 10.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

sometimes a mysql_upgrade will not fix this, which will fail with below error
mysql.gtid_slave_pos
Error : Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine
status : Operation failed

In that case, you will have to recreate the tables. 
http://alidba.blogspot.in/2017/05/table-mysqlgtidslavepos-doesnt-exist.html